# SQL - left pad with the zero after symbol '-'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to left pad with a single zero after the '-'.
I did check the other answers here but didnt help me.

Here is the table :

```
+---------+
|   Job   |
+---------+
| 3254-1  |
| 3254-25 |
| 3254-6  |
+---------+
```

I need to left pad with single zero after '-' if the value is between 1 and 9 in the end

I want the results to be  :

```
+---------+
|   Job   |
+---------+
| 3254-01 |
| 3254-25 |
| 3254-06 |
+---------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What were the problems you had?

Comment: You need to separate the integer values before and after the dash. Then format them separately. Finally, assemble them back together.

Comment: @theimpaler can i do that in a single select statement?

Comment: @ larnu i tried something like this but doesnt work : Select 
case 
when
right(job,2) between '1' and '9'
then '0' + right(job,2)
else #job.job
end as job
from #job

Comment: UPDATE job SET job=replace(job,'-','-0') WHERE len(job)=6

Comment: @raider What you tried was comparing strings alphabetically, not integers numerically. `'12'` is between `'100'` and `'200'` just like `'cart'` is between `'cam'` and `'cat'`, you compare them one character at a time from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CHARINDEX()`, `SUBSTRING()` and `REPLACE()` as:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs(
    Job VARCHAR(45)
    );
INSERT INTO Jobs VALUES
('3254-1'),
('3254-25'),
('3254-6');

SELECT   CASE 
           WHEN CHARINDEX('-', Job, 1)+1 < LEN(Job) THEN Job
           ELSE
               REPLACE(Job, '-', '-0') 
           END AS Job
FROM Jobs;
```

Results:

```
+----+---------+
|    |   Job   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 3254-01 |
|  2 | 3254-25 |
|  3 | 3254-06 |
+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an update, I think this is the simplest method:

```
update t
    set job = replace(job, '-', '-0')
    where job like '%-_';
```

This problem is simplified greatly because you are only adding a single padding character.

Comment: Would [1-9]  be better than the _ in the wildcard?.   Don't know his data though

Answer (score 0):

If you have version `2012+`, then `format` function may be used as :

```
select concat(nr1, '-', format( cast ( q2.nr2 as int ), '00')) as result
  from
 (
  select substring(q1.str,1,charindex('-',q1.str,1)-1) as nr1,
         substring(q1.str,charindex('-',q1.str,1)+1,len(q1.str)) as nr2
    from
    (
     select '3254-1'  as str union all
     select '3254-25' as str union all
     select '3254-6'  as str    
     ) q1
) q2;

 result
 ------
 3254-01
 3254-25
 3254-06
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/FAVIR67206)